# What is an implicit interface?

Tags: c++, interface

I'm reading Effective C++. In item 41 writer says something about differences between explicit and implicit interfaces. I understood explicit interface, but what about implicit?

Comment: You need to explain what you do and don't understand, which parts specifically did not understand?

Comment: Kindly elaborate your Answers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The implicit interface is related to templates.

When you write a template, i.e.:

```
template<typename T>
void func(T param) {
    param.doSomething();
}
```

you expect that the type `T` has a member function `doSomething()`. This member function is part of what the author calls "an implicit interface". You don't declare anywhere the interface

```
class TemplateParam {
public:
    void doSomething();
};
```

but you expect any type that you pass to this template to implement it.